# Magento 2 / Ultimo mini cart error

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, ultimo

I'm using Magento 2.2.2 with the Ultimo theme. Straight away I'm getting an error with the mini cart in the header.

Products can be added to the cart but the mini cart appears to only half load and gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return closeMinicart() }"
Message: $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog is not a function. (In '$('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close')', '$('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog' is undefined)
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Which Ultimo version do you have installed? I am using M2.2.2 and Ultimo 2.6.3, everything works fine

Comment: It's version 2.4.0, I can see if an upgrade fixes the problem.

Comment: It looks like upgrading Ultimo to version 2.7.1 has fixed the problem :)

Comment: Nice:) I wrote it as an answer, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade your Ultimo. I am using M2.2.2 with Ultimo 2.6.3 and everything works fine